# Aptitude: Show What Repo a Package is From, Listing Contents of a Repo

Tags: repository, amazon-web-services, fabric, yum, aptitude

I am trying to prepare an AWS instance by installing some software, one of which is Fabric for Python, a SSH connection library.

By default, AWS's yum doesn't have access to a Fabric distribution to install, so I was attempting to figure out where Aptitude would get Fabric from.

I can't figure out a way to get what repo Fabric is in using Aptitude, or Yum for that matter.

Also, on a similar note, if I do have the url of a specific repo, how would I go about listing all of the packages it has available?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `apt-cache policy` to get that information (`aptitude` uses the same repositories as shown with `apt-cache policy`).

```
apt-cache policy fabric
```

Shows version and repository information about the fabric package.

As pointed out in another answer, you can also use

```
aptitude versions fabric
```

to get more or less the same information (in a slightly different format).

Comment: `aptitude versions somepackage` does **not** show the repository; an information like `http://deb.debian.org/debian` isn't returned.

Answer (score 3):

To show available repository using aptitude you can try:

```
$ aptitude versions fabric 
Package fabric:                        
p   1.4.3-1                                                   testing,unstable                       990
```

This should display all available repositories for the package and it will also list the policy priority at the end. Maybe also check /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: As it is obvious from the provided example output, `aptitude versions somepackage` does **not** show the repository; an information like `http://deb.debian.org/debian` isn't returned.

Comment: @Abdull that's true, it doesn't return a URL, just the names of the repositories that contain the package (like "stable", "testing", or "unstable"). If the package isn't in any repository, `aptitude versions` returns nothing in the third columns instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure this is a stack overflow problem: seems more a system admin than a software dev question. In any case, I'm also not sure you can use Aptitude with YUM: Aptitude typically uses `apt-get` on Debian-based platforms, while yum is generally for Fedora/Red-hat platforms.

From a command line on a machine with the package installed you can typically do:

`dpkg -l | grep <package>` to list all matching installed packages and then do `apt-cache madison <packagename>` to see what repo the package came from.